# Get Value of Child Object with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, magicsuggest

I have a JSON collection produced from an object graph.  Shown below is an example value.  I am having trouble accessing the nested 'Type' object to retrieve any of it's values.

```
[{"Id":1,"Name":"My Name","Type":{"Id":1,"Name":"my Value"}}]
```

I am using a JS component that has a property that can be assigned a value similar to below.

myProperty: Type.Name,  //Not working

Can someone recommend how I set this value?

Comment: This is not JSON, it's just JavaScript, and what you've shown is a regular old JavaScript Array. To get the `Type` value, you'd start with something like `yourArray[0].Type`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is a JavaScript array, not an object, and certainly not JSON.  So if you have

```
var arr = [{"Id":1,"Name":"My Name","Type":{"Id":1,"Name":"my Value"}}]
```

you'd need to index it, and grab the Type object off of *that*.

```
var typeName = arr[0].Type.Name;
```